# Set negative margin on View programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I know how to set margins of a `View` programmatically with `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` and the method `setMargins(int, int, int, int)` but how can I put a negative margin on a view?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Access the layout params for your parent layout and modify them as you like:

```
 ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params =
         (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams)view.getLayoutParams();
 params.topMargin = ...; // etc
 // or
 params.setMargins(...);
```

After you've modified the layout, call `view.requestLayout()`.

Comment: I'm getting the error:  `Should pass resolved pixel dimension instead of resource id here: getResources().getDimension*(-100)`   when putting a negative integer into the second line.

Comment: `val param = (cardSearch.layoutParams as ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams)
param.topMargin = (-searchHeight/2) - listTotalScrollY
cardSearch.requestLayout()`

Answer (score 0):

Using math seems to trick it enough for me.

```
 ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params =
     (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams)view.getLayoutParams();
 params.topMargin = 100 - 200;   // -100
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
params.setMargins(0,5-10,0,0);
```

no

```
params.setMargins(0,-5,0,0);
```